# Is there a name for the way George Strait phrases his lines?

Tags: terminology, country-and-western, phrasing

When looking at the sheet music I have noticed that most of his phrasing is at the end or beginning of a Measure in a very short choppy line. Is there a name for this style of phrasing?

For example, "Amarillo by Morning, the first measure of singing is just a pickup line and then only one quarter note on the second line.

[image: "Amarillo by Morning", page 1]

[image: "Troubadour", page 1]

[image: "Write This Down", page 1]

Comment: "most of his phrasing is that _the end or beginning of a Measure in a very short choppy line_" – I guess this was meant to be a sentence, but a verb is missing.

Comment: “Looking” is a verb, no?